# Leiningen is installed but I Get Error When Attempting to Run

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

I have Leiningen installed on my computer here: /usr/local/bin/lein (version 2.7.1)

I have Java installed here: /usr/bin/java (version 1.8.0_74)

I have set Leiningen it to be executable, and yet when I go to run "lein", I get the following error message:

```
"java.lang.Exception: Error loading /Users/jessierichardson/Desktop/project.clj
 at leiningen.core.project$read_raw$fn__6407.invoke (project.clj:962)
    leiningen.core.project$read_raw.invokeStatic (project.clj:956)
    leiningen.core.project$read_raw.invoke (project.clj:952)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invokeStatic (project.clj:973)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invoke (project.clj:970)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invokeStatic (project.clj:974)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invoke (project.clj:970)
    leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__5998.invoke (main.clj:397)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.invokeStatic (main.clj:394)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke (main.clj:391)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:397)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:375)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:152)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic (main.clj:314)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invoke (main.clj:310)
    clojure.main$main.invokeStatic (main.clj:421)
    clojure.main$main.doInvoke (main.clj:384)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:421)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:383)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:156)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.main.main (main.java:37)
Caused by: clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: bookmark88 in this context, compiling:(/Users/jessierichardson/Desktop/project.clj:0:0)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze (Compiler.java:6688)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze (Compiler.java:6625)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6931)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.load (Compiler.java:7379)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile (Compiler.java:7317)
    clojure.lang.RT$3.invoke (RT.java:320)
    leiningen.core.project$read_raw$fn__6407.invoke (project.clj:960)
    leiningen.core.project$read_raw.invokeStatic (project.clj:956)
    leiningen.core.project$read_raw.invoke (project.clj:952)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invokeStatic (project.clj:973)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invoke (project.clj:970)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invokeStatic (project.clj:974)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invoke (project.clj:970)
    leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__5998.invoke (main.clj:397)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.invokeStatic (main.clj:394)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke (main.clj:391)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:397)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:375)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:152)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic (main.clj:314)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invoke (main.clj:310)
    clojure.main$main.invokeStatic (main.clj:421)
    clojure.main$main.doInvoke (main.clj:384)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:421)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:383)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:156)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.main.main (main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: bookmark88 in this context
 at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.resolveIn (Compiler.java:7164)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.resolve (Compiler.java:7108)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSymbol (Compiler.java:7069)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze (Compiler.java:6648)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze (Compiler.java:6625)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6931)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.load (Compiler.java:7379)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile (Compiler.java:7317)
    clojure.lang.RT$3.invoke (RT.java:320)
    leiningen.core.project$read_raw$fn__6407.invoke (project.clj:960)
    leiningen.core.project$read_raw.invokeStatic (project.clj:956)
    leiningen.core.project$read_raw.invoke (project.clj:952)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invokeStatic (project.clj:973)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invoke (project.clj:970)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invokeStatic (project.clj:974)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invoke (project.clj:970)
    leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__5998.invoke (main.clj:397)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.invokeStatic (main.clj:394)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke (main.clj:391)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:397)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:375)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:152)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic (main.clj:314)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invoke (main.clj:310)
    clojure.main$main.invokeStatic (main.clj:421)
    clojure.main$main.doInvoke (main.clj:384)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:421)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:383)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:156)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.main.main (main.java:37)"
```

I have a project in Clojure that I did several months ago that lein runs fine in and am up to date with current versions of lein and java.

Could someone please help?

Comment: The error isn't caused by leiningen

Comment: Thanks- could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `lein` from a directory that is a lein project (has a project.clj file), it will try to parse the project file even though you did not give it any commands.  If you run `lein` from a directory that is not a project, it will at least print out the commands available, as there's no project file to read.

There is an error "Unable to resolve symbol `bookmark88`" in the text above.  This is in your `project.clj` file.  Paste its contents to your original question if you need help, or examine it yourself to determine the problem.  This is the reason you can't run lein.

I would recommend you put your project in its own directory, not on your desktop, as it seems you currently are.  Then in your terminal change to the project directory (the one that contains `project.clj`) and run `lein` from there.

Comment: Thanks Josh. It actually is in it's own directory, it's just that the directory is on the dekstop. And I tried to create a new project by doing "lein new myproj", also tried "lein new app myproj" which I saw in some threads. I can't even get the version of Leiningen or use the repl from this folder so it seems like it lacks permission. Tried making it executable to by doing chmod 755 *path_name and chmod a + x *pathname to no success.

Comment: @JessieRichardson The top line of your stack trace seems to indicate that lein cannot properly read a project.clj that is in your Desktop folder.  At any rate, two things to check.  First, in your home directory look for a directory called `.lein` and see if there is a `profiles.clj` in that directory and look at that for errors.  Second, create an entirely new directory, go into it, and try `lein new projname` -- are you saying that even this fails?

Comment: Thanks- I will try that. And yes, when I try to create a new project in a new directory that fails.